# Do intersections commute with direct sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, direct-sum

This is just a basic linear algebra question without that much context to it.  I'm wondering if the following identity holds for vector spaces:
$$ (A \oplus  B)  \cap C  = (A \oplus 0 )\cap C  + (0 \oplus B)\cap C. $$

My intuition tells me it's always true, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if my post answers exactly what you're asking. If so, tell me and i'll edit it.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Now you have a detailed proof of my answer. Hope you undertand it, tell if you see something confusing.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No, vector spaces don't verify that:
$$(A \oplus  B)  \cap C  = (A\cap C)  \oplus (B\cap C).$$
To prove it, we can find a counterexpample:

Consider the vector subspaces $\langle\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\rangle$, $\langle\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\rangle$ and $\langle\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\rangle$. Notice that
$$\left(\langle\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\rangle\oplus \langle\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\rangle\right)\cap \langle\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\rangle=\mathbb{R}^2\cap \langle\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\rangle=\langle\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\rangle,$$
but
$$\left(\langle\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\rangle  \cap \langle\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\rangle\right)\oplus\left(\langle\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\rangle  \cap \langle\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\rangle\right)=0\oplus 0=0,$$
and clearly $\langle\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\rangle\neq 0$.

Comment: And  does this hold: $(V \cap A) \oplus (V \cap B) = V$, for $ V \subset A \oplus B$ ?

Comment: Oh it does by what you just said

Comment: I'm working on a proof. I'll edit it soon.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso In your proof, why $x$ in $A \bigoplus B$ means $x \in A$ or $x \in B$? direct sum means $x=x_1 + x_2, x_1 \in A, x_2 \in B  $ is the unique way, but maybe $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$.

Comment: Oh, i see you're right. I'll edit to correct it.

Comment: I have edited one proof for it, tell if something wrong.

Comment: In the first part of the proof, how do we know that $x_1\in C$ and $x_2\in C$? Just because their sum is in $C$, doesn't guarantee that they themselves are in $C$...

Comment: @ET-phone-homology Oh, I see. You're right, my proof is wrong, I didn't see that mistake back when I tried proving it. I've tried to delete my answer but I can't because it's accepted.

Answer (score 13):

This is so wrong...

Let $A=Span(1,0), B=Span(0,1), C=Span(1,1)$.
Then
$$(A\oplus B)\cap C=\mathbb{R}^2\cap C=C$$ and
$$(A\cap C)\oplus (B\cap C)=0\oplus 0 = 0.$$

Answer (score -5):

Let $\mathbf{A,B,C}$ are subspaces of finite-dimension vector space, then
$(A\bigoplus B)\bigcap C = (A\bigcap C)\bigoplus (B\bigcap C)$.

Proof:

1. For all $x \in (A\bigoplus B)\bigcap C$, we have $x\in (A\bigoplus
           B)$ and $x\in C$. Then $x$ can be represented by $x=x_1 + x_2, x_1
           \in A, x_2 \in B$ (for unique representation in direct sum),
       $x_1,x_2 \in  (A\bigoplus B)\bigcap C$ (closed additive). So $x_1
       \in C, x_2 \in C$. Then  $x_1 \in A \bigcap C, x_2 \in B \bigcap C$,
       it concludes that $ x=x_1 + x_2 \in (A\bigcap C)\bigoplus (B\bigcap
       C)$, which implies that $(A\bigoplus B)\bigcap C \subseteq (A\bigcap
       C)\bigoplus (B\bigcap C)$.
2. For all $x \in (A\bigcap C)\bigoplus (B\bigcap C)$, we have $x = x_1
           + x_2, x_1 \in (A\bigcap C), x_2 \in (B\bigcap C) $.
                Then $x=x_1 + x_2 \in (A \bigoplus B)$ and $x=x_1 + x_2 \in C$(closed additive). It concludes that $(A\bigcap C)\bigoplus
           (B\bigcap C) \subseteq (A\bigoplus B)\bigcap C$.
3. From (1),(2) , it concludes that $(A\bigoplus B)\bigcap C =
   (A\bigcap C)\bigoplus (B\bigcap C)$.

Comment: It seems correct to me. Thanks!